# Passing String to Controller using AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

I've been trying this out for about a day already and looked through multiple questions and answers and still unable to solve this.

Regardless, my `name` value will always be `null` or end up with a bad request error 400. Really would appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Javascript:

```
var myPerson = {};
    myPerson.name = "Brandon";

    function createObject() {
        $.ajax({
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Person/CreatePerson',
            data: JSON.stringify(myPerson),
            success: function (response) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(myPerson);
            }, error: function (e) {
                alert(e.responseText);
            }

        })
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreatePerson(string name)
    {
        Person person = new Person();

        person.Name = name;

        _context.Person.Add(person);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Json(person);
    }
```

[alert results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILY1f.jpg)

Comment: remove `contentType: 'application/json'`, there's no real need for it. Just send the data in the normal form-encoded format

Comment: Still returns blank, response returns [object Object]

Comment: So are you now saying the name property isn't posted or the response is wrong?

Comment: If you alert an object is will say `[object Object]` because it's an object...

Comment: name property isn't posted, my alert response comes out as [object Object]

Comment: that's because it's an object try `alert(response.Name);`

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringify(response));` will give you a better idea of the response data. `response` is a JSON object, not plain text, so you can't just print it directly

Comment: changed accordingly and i just edited to show the response, my name is still null

Comment: Have you tried the FromBody suggestion as below?

Comment: @ADyson Yes i did, encounter a server status error 415

Comment: Look at my updated answer please. I didn't see that you are trying to send a Person obj. I just thought you wanted to send a string

Comment: Having seen your edit, can you change to simply `data: myPerson.name`. Not sure why you are sending a stringified version of the whole object. Your controller is only expecting a single string. Or do the opposite as per Anastasios' updated answer. Either way make sure the JS and the controller match up in terms of what's being sent and in what structure.

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis I changed according to the new update below and still receives error 415

Comment: update: i added in back   'contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8" ' and it worked ! Thank you so much for the help and sorry for being so lost, really really thank you for all your help @AnastasiosSelmanis

Comment: @ADyson Thank you so much for your help too ! Really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been struggling too with this because I thought it was very weird. In ASP.NET Core 2.0 you have to add a `[FromBody]` before your parameters in your action. [Here](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) is why.

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson([FromBody] string name)
```

For the Person response you might need this

```
return Json(new {person = person});
```

Read it in your ajax like this:

```
var person = response.person
```

**UPDATE**

Since you want to pass the person object do the following

```
var myPerson = {
    "Name" = "personName"
};
```

Pass it like this

```
data: JSON.stringify(myPerson)
```

And get it to the controller like this:

```
public ActionResult CreatePerson([FromBody] Person myPerson)
```

Comment: `var person = JSON.parse(response);`...no because `dataType: "json"` in the ajax options ensures that jQuery has already parsed it into an object. OP's issue (as per comments) is in displaying that, for which the opposite - stringify - is required

Comment: "You have to also add the property dataType "...it's already there in the original code. And why are you proposing making the response object more complex?

Comment: Added this and encountered this error :Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 ()